# Python issue for crawling multiple page title

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am a marketer and want to conduct some basic market research using Python.

I wrote a simple coding to crawl multiple pages of title, but it does not work to put the title text in the list and to transfer it into Excel format. How can I do in this case?
I tried to create a `list` and used the `extend()` method to put these looped titles on the list, but it did not work:

```python
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def content_get(url):
    count = 0
    while count < 4:                 #this case was to crawl titles of 4 pages
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
        titles = soup.find(id="main-container").find_all("div", class_="r-ent")
        for title in titles:
            print([title.find('div', class_='title').text])
        nextpageurl = soup.find("a", string="‹ 上頁")["href"]
        url = "https://www.ptt.cc" + nextpageurl
        count += 1

firstpage = "https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/movie/index9002.html"
content_get(firstpage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the titles to a list outside of the `while` loop:

```py
def content_get(url):
    count = 0
    titles = []

    while count < 4:                
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

        title_page = [title.text.replace('\n', '') for title in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'title'})]            
        titles.extend(title_page)

        nextpageurl = soup.find("a", string="‹ 上頁")["href"]
        url = "https://www.ptt.cc" + nextpageurl
        count += 1
    return titles
```

If you don't want the list comprehension to get `titles_page`, that can be replaced with a traditional `for` loop:

```py
titles_page = []
titles = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'title'})
for title in titles:
    titles_page.append(title.text.replace('\n', ''))
```

For the excel file:

```py
def to_excel(text):
    df = pd.DataFrame(text, columns=['Title'])
    return df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```